# Bash Shell - What is equivalent of DOS shell F8?

Tags: linux, bash

When working an interactive bash session, one aspect from the Windows shell I miss is the <kbd>F8</kbd> key where you start typing a command, hit <kbd>F8</kbd> and the shell finds the most recent command entered in history that matches what you have typed so far. e.g.

```
me@Ubntu07:~>cd /home/jb<F8 Key Here>
```

brings up my prior command:

```
me@Ubntu07:~>cd /home/jboss/server/default/log
```

Is there any way to do this in bash ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> before you start typing.

(There may well be another version which finds commands based on what's already been typed - I wouldn't know, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> has always been good enough for me :)

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> again shows the next match etc.

Comment: Note that if you tape after your first Ctrl-R, you will restrict the search in the history to entries matching what you typed; you can then alternate between Ctrl-R and typing to find quickly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

My Gentoo is configured in a way that I can press PgUp and PgDn to scroll through those commands in the command history that start with what’s currently in my command line.

```
# cd<PgUp>
```

results in:

```
# cd hydrogen
```

That’s pretty much the same function. It is defined in my `/etc/inputrc` with the following lines:

```
# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end 
# of the history
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Comment: I have something similar in tcsh. I have it mapped to Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down instead, so I can have normal history-browsing as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have these lines in my .inputrc file:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

This binds history search to the up and down arrow keys. So you can start typing a command, `kextload` say, and then each tap of the up arrow will complete the line with the previous command that started with `kextload`.

All of my config files are public on github.

http://github.com/jonshea/config-files/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

In your case `!jb` would print *and then run* that command.

e.g.,

```
$ nano logconfig.properties
$ !n
nano logconfig.properties
$
```

Of course if you want to be on the safe side, use ctrl-r first to bring up the interactive command history.

Comment: His command starts "cd /home/jb"; "!jb" would not run his command. "!?jb?" might do it, but it also might run some other command that had the letters "jb" in it.

Comment: If you get in doubt once you've already typed the ! and search part of the query, you can force in-place expansion with M-^.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> does a history search. It's a bit different in that *first* you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and *then* type what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just talking about a command, you can use the `!<cmd>` to do the last one. For example, say you entered `python runscript.py` a while ago; you can type:

```
!py
```

or something along those lines to run that command again.

To repeat an argument to a command, you could do something like this:

```
echo !py:1
```

which would echo `runscript.py` back to the terminal, in this example. The number after the colon refers to the argument you'd like to use from the given command.

There's a lot of other great information about the bash history [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/?).

Answer (score 1):

If you use vi input mode (set -o vi in bash or via set editing-mode vi in .inputrc), you can use normal vi commands to search the history (/).  This gives you full regular expressions, too, which can be helpful for finding a complex command.